# bootstrap navigation modification

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to modify a bootstrap navigation bar and every time I try to modify the CSS with my own it doesn't seem to take. I have a hamburger menu icon that I only want to appear in mobile so I modified the  in my CSS to display:none; for media queries over 769px and display:inline; for displays under 768px. The button still appears on desktops.
HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">HOME<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="pages/about.html">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="blog.php">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="pages/video.html">VIDEOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="pages/photos.html">PHOTOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="pages/podcasts.html">PODCASTS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="pages/recaps">RACE RECAPS</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a> 
    </div>
    </nav>
```

The CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width 769px) {
button .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-left {
    display:none;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width 768px) {
button .navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-left {
    display:inline;
}
}
```

Note: I've tried the CSS without the "button" and just the classes as well. I've also tried wrapping the button in a div as well, no luck.

Comment: ETA: "I tried wrapping the button in a div as well." Is what that sentence should say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css class selectors shouldn't have spaces if they refer to the same element:

```
@media screen and (min-width 769px) {
button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-left {
display:none;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width 768px) {
button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-left {
display:inline;
}
}
```

**Edit**

Also add the colons in min-width: 769px and max-width: 768px.

Comment: That did not work for me. Button still shows on Desktops.

Comment: Is it online for us to see?

Comment: Also try adding colons in max-width: 768px and min-width: 769px.

Comment: THAT did the trick. That's the problem with code, the smallest oversight can trip you up. Thank you Dan

Answer (score 0):

[Here is working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KayXPb)

Spaces look for descendants left to right.

Unless you are using .navbar-toggler somewhere else it is unnecessary to add every class of the element

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
     .navbar-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .navbar-toggler {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```